# Best practice to pull new Google Form responses

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-forms, google-sheets-api

I'm writing an application that programatically pulls and processes responses submitted from a Google Form. The implementation so far has been to use google's v4 sheet api and poll the sheet (at 1Hz) for new rows, i.e. new responses.

Running multiple instances of my application has led me to hit the quota limit, and it's clear that polling isn't the right way of doing it, an event-driven approach (onFormSubmit) would be way better, but I don't see a good way of doing this.

Has anyone developed more mature approach to programmatically getting new responses from a Google Form? I'm currently using python, but am open to other languages.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, the data in the Google Form needs to be sent out to an external place?  You can make an HTTPS Request from Apps Script to an external place.

Comment: Yes, that seems like the right way to go about it, but would require more infrastructure on the application. Currently the application is able to run locally without any public facing APIs. In this way, polling was designed to avoid that extra infrastructure.

Comment: I still don't understand what you want.  I guess that you are polling the Google Form on some time interval and finding response(s) that are not in that data store yet.  Do you want it to run faster?  You want something that is "more mature", but in relation to what? We have no idea what your staring point is.

Answer (score 1):

There is an On Submit event object which can be run inside your receiving spreadsheet.  You set your function to run on a form submit.  See the main [Event Objects page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events).  In your case you want an [Installable Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).  To do this:

- open your Code in the Code Editor
- Under the Edit menu select **Current project's triggers**
- If you have no triggers set up, click the line to add one.
- Set your trigger settings to: ~ (Name of your function to run) ~ **From spreadsheet** ~ and **On form submit**